# R says lm.fit wants a matrix

Tags: r, types, lm

I'm learning R in the context of a course, and I'm getting an error message that I don't understand. I load data from a file giving by the instructor to get `x` and `y`:

```
> load("7.R.RData")
> ls()
[1] "x" "y"
```

Now I try to fit OLS, but that fails:

```
> lm.fit(y ~ x)
Error in lm.fit(y ~ x) : 'x' must be a matrix
```

I'm not really sure what `x` is. `class` tells me it's "numeric" and printing its first ten values look like this:

```
> class(x)
[1] "numeric"
> x[1:10]
 [1] 140.1638 140.4303 140.9321 141.7705 140.0042 141.7460 141.8617 141.1520
```

Naively, I tried converting `x` to a matrix, but that doesn't change anything:

```
> x = matrix(x)
> lm.fit(y ~ x)
Error in lm.fit(y ~ x) : 'x' must be a matrix
```

Googling for this error message didn't turn up anything.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, found it while typing the question. Being used to scikit-learn, statsmodels and other Python tools, I confused `lm` and `lm.fit`. The latter is a low-level fitting routine with calling conventions

```
lm.fit (x, y,    offset = NULL, method = "qr", tol = 1e-7,
       singular.ok = TRUE, ...)
```

So, the error message is complaining about the first argument, the formula, not my `x`. I should have used

```
lm(y ~ x)
```

Comment: When in doubt always consult the documentation: `help("lm.fit")`. Btw., `lm.fit(x, y)` is not the same as `lm(y ~ x)`. The former doesn't include an intercept, the latter does. To include an intercept, you'd need `lm.fit(cbind(1, x), y)`.

Comment: @Roland: removed the final note on `lm.fit`, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use lm.fit
lm.fit(matrix(x,length(x),1),y)
And sometimes people prefer calling lm.fit for performance.Because lm calls lm.fit internally and it does some extra jon which might be time consuming if you want to run many times lm.